# jQuery script stops when when calling function on other jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

UPDATE: https://staging.mac-recycle.com/quote/ (Live)

It calls `ddslick()` fine with no errors now but won't get the value (1) from the `#demo-htmlselect` to show the next div.

If I remove the `$('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick();` function it pulls the value fine and shows the div (show me on select value 1).

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js">
</script>

    <select id="demo-htmlselect">
        <option  value="0">Please select</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="https://staging.mac-recycle.com/wp- 
        content/uploads/2020/11/macbook-pro.png">MacBook Pro</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="https://staging.mac-recycle.com/wp- 
        content/uploads/2020/11/macbook-air.png">MacBook Air</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    $('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick();
    </script>

<div id="1" class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
    <div class="frm_opt_container">
     show me on select value 1
     </div>
</div>


<script>
$(function() {   
    $('#demo-htmlselect').change(function(){
        $('.hiddenDiv').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have your script tags all over the place in the document?

Comment: To make it clearer to read in calling order

Comment: You need to load jquery *before* ddsclick (and before `jQuery.noConflict`),  You're also loading ddsclick twice.  Check in the browser console, you'll have a number of errors:  `$ is undefined` `.ddslick is undefined`

Comment: You'll also probably be getting an error that you can't link directly to raw.githubusercontent.com and you'll need to find a CDN or copy the file to your project

Comment: Removed ddslick.min & put jQuery first. Changed the $j back to $ as don't need the no conflict but the value is still not been called from the demo-htmlselect drop down option

ddslick is working and no errors but still not getting the value from the option

Comment: Might be worth a review of the documentation:  https://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick   `$('#demo-htmlselect').data('ddslick');`.  I'll recommend using [select2](https://select2.org/) if you want images in a drop down, it has many additional features that you may need.

Comment: OK will bare this in mind thank you, still trying to figure out how to pull the value of the option with ddslick called